# Weird ffmpeg behavior - "-shortest" flag ends the audio too early

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate some video files using `ffmpeg`, but when I use the `-shortest` flag, I get a file whose audio stream is several seconds shorter than its video stream.
I tried several configurations, but it seems that for some unknown (to me) reason, `ffmpeg` keep ending the audio stream about 8.3 seconds too early.

My actual situation is quite complicated (I'm using `image2pipe` to turn a stream of automatically-generated images into video, and using `apad` to make sure the audio stream extends until the video ends), but for simplicity and reproducibility, I will give a simple example:

I'm using the command `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i "images/*.bmp" -i audio.mp3 -r 30 -shortest output.mp4`.
The directory `images` contains 600 copies of https://samples-files.com/samples/Images/bmp/480-360-sample.bmp, and `audio.mp3` is https://samples-files.com/samples/Audio/mp3/sample-file-3.mp3 (which is a `1m`-long file). The output file I get can be seen at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BCRhafFhTa8G-RPspv6o6ji2h6fRm8C0/view. As you can see, it plays fine until about `11s`, then it suddenly continue without audio. (Using `mediainfo`, I can confirm that the file duration is `20s`, and that's also the duration of the video stream, but the duration of the audio stream is `11.657s`).

My ffmpeg version is `6.0-6ubuntu1`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: try to update to 6.1

Comment: Thank you. Look like it solved it.